# Javascript library for BlackBerry

Tags: javascript, blackberry, jquery-plugins, mobile-website

I'm currently starting in the web mobile development along with come trench brothers. I've done some things for iPhone and Android using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [JQTouch](http://www.jqtouch.com/). Recently we've been playing with the idea to also support **BlackBerry** devices to an application we are developing (which promises a lot of rework). Our initial tests with the BlackBerry simulators were a disaster... practically nothing works as expected (styles, jQuery ui components, etc..). So we believe jQtouch ended not being the silver bullet for this job (wierd huh? =P ).

We are now looking for a jQtouch-like library for BlackBerry's older models (Bold, Curve, Storm, Storm2... Torch has a Webkit implementation so it works like a charm).

Any ideas?

**Update:** ----

Im currently working with [XUI](http://xuijs.com/) which is the only option I have found for OS4.6 and 5. Its really light weight and wraps up some issues nicely. I'm only concerned on the poor documentation it has and the fact that there are almost no extensions/plugins so you basically need to create the UI components you require from scratch (which sucks big time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None exist for the older OS before 6.0.

Only basic Javascript and CSS work, like version 2.0.

The old browser was terrible, more like IE(I would even say worst) you see my point.

jQuery mobile will probably support it in a near future : http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/

So, stick to basic mobile web site for the BlackBerry older than 6.0.

Comment: Its sad to hear what you already knew when you are hopping to be wrong... But you are right, there is nothing out there but the hope that jquerymobile may support BB.